# When using folder redirection, cannot access C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop path. Broken link?

Tags: folder-redirection

I'm testing out Folder Redirection for several folders and I have my Desktop redirected to a network share. I created a script, saved it to my Desktop, and I'm trying to run it in an elevated CMD. However, I cannot CD into C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop in order to run the script!

I would assume that there would be some sort of link to the shared location. I've been having quite a bit of trouble with Folder Redirection so far, and I had to recover/recreate some folders, so perhaps I lost whatever link was there. Or is this behavior by design?

If there is supposed to be a link to the redirected Desktop, how do I recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder redirection doesn't work by using Junctions or anything fancy, it simply sets some registry values to tell Windows to literally load a different location instead of the defaults. The old locations may still exist explicitly but they will have no bearing on the new location, anyway.

Because you can't use UNC paths in a command prompt you won't be able to do exactly what you want. A work around may be to use a mapped drive, but I don't know if this is supported now. I'd advise avoiding it where possible, though.